# subversion checkout only modified files in jenkins

Tags: svn

Is there any way to check out only modified files through subversion commands because I want only modified files to be in my working copy Jenkins to build only modified files?

Comment: How could you be sure that you will only commit files which work individually and not need files from previous commits? (You can delete from the repository you do not want to compile.)

Comment: how to check out files modified between two dates through svn commands

Comment: I guess that is a different question.

Comment: yes true but  i think i may get solution  through this if you could help

Comment: svn diff -r{2015-02-12}:{2015-04-28}  https://user-PC/svn/demo/../  > d:output.txt through this command i may able to get a log files inside that i can see how many files have changed

Answer (score 0):

Subversion 1.8 updates modified items in working copy only. It does not fetch all data from the server, only modified items. Moreover, Subversion 1.8 has major efficiency improvements in this: http://subversion.apache.org/docs/release-notes/1.8.html#pristines.